MethodInfo of the method on the Refit client interface that was invoked
This is my refit interface in.NET 6:
[Get("/api/users/records")]
Task<ApiResponseMessage<GetUsersResponse>> GetUsersAsync(
    GetUsersRequest request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

If I want to retrieve the details about the request at the run time. I can use the following code : Code from Github of Refit Library
class RequestPropertyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public RequestPropertyHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler = null) : base(innerHandler ?? new HttpClientHandler()) {}

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get the type of the target interface
        Type interfaceType = (Type)request.Properties[HttpMessageRequestOptions.InterfaceType];

        var builder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
        // Alter the Path in some way based on the interface or an attribute on it
        builder.Path = $"/{interfaceType.Name}{builder.Path}";
        // Set the new Uri on the outgoing message
        request.RequestUri = builder.Uri;

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

But I am interested to know the response type, for example in my case GetUsersResponse.
How can I achieve the response type of the current request being executed by the Refit Client?
